# Meteor Mongo Document update difference beween calling update(id) vs update({_id: id))

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Can anyone explain what is the difference between calling

update(id) (without object) vs update({_id: id)) (with object)

Eg:

```
var id = "TByq2TNcyPrpcu9nu";

Tasks.update(id, {$set: {name: "hello"}});
```

and

```
Tasks.update({_id: id}, {$set: {name: "hello"}});
```

Both the case seems to work properly though. Which is the correct approach and the reason?

Comment: Both are correct : while the first has been imagined to be a shortcut, the second is the logical way for those who are not aware of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference. The first way is just sugar for the second way.